# Call a handler function on event

Tags: jquery, html

I believe it is possible to call a function in an event handler, just like this:

```
$([selector]).[event](function(){
    handlerFunction();
});
```

Is there a way of doing this in a more compact way? like this:

```
$([selector]).[event](handlerFunction());
```

In any case, how do you pass to `handlerFunction()` the element in which you're calling the event handler? Is it done implicitly? Is it needed a parameter both in the calling and function? 
I got an unique handler function which behaves differently depending on the item that calls it and I don't know how to pass that info and even if this is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$([selector]).[event](handlerFunction);
```

The element that triggered the event gets passed to `handlerFunction` via the `this` keyword:

```
function handlerFunction() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

In this example, handlerFunction would hide the element that triggered the action. Notice that `this` is the DOM element, `$(this)` the jQuery equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the handlerFunction as reference, like this:

```
$([selector]).[event](handlerFunction);
```

If you use handlerFunction(), the function will be called, and the return value will be passed to the event handler

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
$([selector]).[event](handlerFunction)
```

Don't put `()` after `handlerFunction` or else you'll call it immediately and use its *return value* as the function to run, which won't work because it doesn't return anything.
To access the element inside `handlerFunction`, use `$(this)`, llike `$(this).html('triggered!')`.